# Programmatically follow a site with JSOM but error message is a lie?

Tags: javascript, social, following, jsom

I try to follow a page with JavaScript Object Model.
My solution is based on many examples in the web and should work...

```
var siteActorInfo = new SP.Social.SocialActorInfo();        
siteActorInfo.set_contentUri(siteInfo.Url);
siteActorInfo.set_accountName(accountName);
siteActorInfo.set_actorType(4);

if (siteInfo.Followed)
    followingManager.follow(siteActorInfo);
else
    followingManager.stopFollowing(siteActorInfo);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
    if (onSuccess) onSuccess();
}, function (a,error) {
    if (onError) onError(error.get_message());
});
```

But when I try to follow or unfollow the page, I get this error:

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: actor.ActorType

The `SP.Social.SocialFollowingManager` is initialized in another function and generally works.

It was not a problem to retrieve the list of followed sites.

I don't understand, whats the problem here.

Instead of 4 I also tried `SP.Social.SocialActorTypes.sites`, but this makes, no difference of course, because the value of the property is 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can isolate the problem by trying to execute below in Console and check if error is still appearing

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var socialManager = new SP.Social.SocialFollowingManager(context);
var socialSite = new SP.Social.SocialActorInfo();
socialSite.set_contentUri("https://siteurl");
socialSite.set_actorType(SP.Social.SocialActorType.site);
socialManager.follow(socialSite);

context.executeQueryAsync(
    function() { alert('Sites followed!'); },
    function(sender, args) { alert('Error: ' + args.get_message()); });
```

Comment: With the isolated code it works. At the end, I was successful with my code but I do not know, what ever has been the problem. I'm pretty sure `SP.Social.SocialActorType.site` had the value 4 this morning. Now it is 2 and using a 4 gives the quoted error, what makes sense. But using the enum I got the same error message. Or I had silly caching problems and worked on old code. Nevermind! Now it works. Thanks :)